# Refer to properties in an xml file, which are defined under a bean in another xml file

Tags: java, xml, spring

## I have a property defined in an xml file - that.xml

## that.xml

## [that.xml code for toReferProperty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwPp9.jpg)

I need to refer to the property - 'toReferProperty' - under the bean - 'thatBean' - in the file - 'that.xml' - in the file 'this.xml' in the below way and then based on that I need to use a property 'newProperty in the 'constructor-arg' as below-

========

## this.xml

## [thisd.xml code for newProperty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVkp1.jpg)

Questions 1: How do I refer to the 'toReferProperty' in that.xml in 'this.xml'?

Question 2: How to use the 'toReferProperty' in the IF else loop in XML syntax?

Question 3: How to refer to 'newProperty' in 'this.xml' in the 'constructor-arg' in same xml?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. If you are trying to do this for different environments, i would recommend using spring Profiles instead of if/else but here's what you need to answer your question.

`that.xml`

```
<bean id="someProperty" class="java.lang.String">
  <constructor-arg value="Hello"/>
</bean>

<bean id="thatBean" class="someClass">      
   <property name="referProperty" ref="someProperty"/>
</bean>
```

`this.xml`

```
<import resource="that.xml" />

<bean id="thisBean" class="someClass">      
   <constructor-arg value="#{ ${someProperty} == Hello ?  newValue1 : newValue2 }"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, the thing is I have a use case of more than 2 values in the decision-making process. So it's just not restricted to newValue1 and newValue2, but there will be newValue3 and newValue4 also.

I don't t think- value="#{ ${someProperty} == Hello ?  newValue1 : newValue2 }

that the above will be useful in that case